# Insert HTML to Jekyll post

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll

I'd like to include some Web Audio API HTML5 code into a Jekyll post. Here's a clone of the HTML page + Javascript code that I'd like to include:

view-source:http://www.smartjava.org/examples/webaudio/example3.html

How should this be achieved?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, if you are using markdown to create your posts, you can use Liquid's **include** tag.

You just have to create a folder with the name **_includes/** in the DocumentRoot of your project, then,  create an HTML file inside, for example "mycomponent.html"  and call it in your post with something like this:

```
{% include mycomponent.html %}
```

This file can have any HTML/CSS/JS you want.

Notice how you include just your HTML file; the external CSS/JS can be included in the layout that you're using.

Comment: I don't think you can use `{% include foo.html %}` within a content of a post or a page. I've tried that it didn't work, and Jekyll's doc says it shouldn't work, either.

Comment: @TengL just tested it and it worked. Within a markdown post (file extensioned with .md), within the content of the post I included the `{% include mytest.html %}` and the post correctly included and rendered the HTML. @kmil0v's answer gets an upvote from me!

Comment: Does not work in posts; using this still renders as plaintext

Answer (score -4):

You can simply write HTML code and it'd work. Learn more [here](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#html-blocks)

Comment: please update your answer to include guidance on how to solve the problem and not just a link to an external resource. try to provide a bit of a summary/description at least